# Blazor Core Hosted - all Components in Razor Class Library Project are being printed as HTML on the page

Tags: .net-core, blazor, razor-class-library

I haven't been able to find the keywords for a similar issue, so I'm posting a new one.

The project was working fine and suddenly the issue described below happened. I was only editing some Razor files from the Razor Class Library, so I was unable to trace it back to any code modification I made.

### The Issue:

I have the following project structure:

[image]

The **Client, Server and Shared** are projects that were initially created by the Blazor Template in the NET Core 3.0. **DesktopClient** is a similar Blazor project with ElectronNET and the issue is also happening on the component over there.The **SharedLibrary** project is the project where the components common to all projects are placed and where the root of the issue is apparently coming from.

The **SharedLibrary** is referenced on the **Client** project so I can access the components in the **Client** project.

What happened is that **suddenly the components from the Razor Class Library stopped being "compiled" and all "@" are being printed as Raw HTML** like the button for the "Counter 2":

[[image]]

Notice as how there are 3 buttons on the image. The first one is in the base Razor page and is being compiled correctly. Second one is from the **SharedLibrary** project and **is not being compiled apparently as the "@" tag is not being replace**d. And the third button is from a Component in the **Client** project(same project as the base Razor page) and is also working correctly.

So the issue is that the **SharedLibrary** Razor files are not being "compiled".

### What I've tried:

- Remove and add reference from project;
- Clean and rebuild solution;
- Update packages;
- Checked .csproj to see if I could find anything wrong/missing (not experienced on this file, so might have missed something).
- Created a new Blazor Core Hosted project and added a Razor Class Library with the same setup as this demo. It worked fine, so the problem in on this project. Dependencies and ".csproj" files seem very similar.

### The code:

.csproj for Client project:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazor.Extensions.SignalR" Version="0.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.HttpClient" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.DevServer" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\SharedLibrary\SharedLibrary.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\ServerAPI.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\SharedLibrary\Content\styles\font\**\*.*">
      <Link>wwwroot\styles\font\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\..\SharedLibrary\Content\images\system\*.*">
      <Link>wwwroot\images\system\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\..\SharedLibrary\Content\images\social\brands\*.*">
      <Link>wwwroot\images\social\brands\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Compile Remove="bin\**" />
    <Content Remove="bin\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="bin\**" />
    <None Remove="bin\**" />
    <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="wwwroot\styles\main.css" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
    <Folder Include="Services\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\images\system\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\scripts\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="compilerconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\styles\main.css">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

.csproj for SharedLibrary

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
    <BlazorLinkOnBuild>false</BlazorLinkOnBuild>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Blazor.Extensions.SignalR" Version="0.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build" Version="3.0.0-preview9.19465.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Content\images\social\brands\" />
    <Folder Include="Core\Login\" />
    <Folder Include="Core\Login\OAuth2\" />
    <Folder Include="Services\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Resources\Languages\en-US.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>en-US.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Languages\en-US.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>en-US.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@using ServerAPI.Client.Components
@using SharedLibrary.Components.User

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    int currentCount = 0;

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
<SocialWithFormLoginComponent />
<Counter />
```

SocialWithFormLoginComponent.razor in SharedLibrary project

```
<h1>Counter 2</h1>

<p>Current count 2: @currentCount2</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount2">Click me 2</button>

@code {
    int currentCount2 = 0;

    void IncrementCount2()
    {
        currentCount2++;
        StateHasChanged();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Counter.razor in Client project

```
<h1>Counter 3</h1>

<p>Current count 3: @currentCount3</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount3">Click me 3</button>

@code {
    int currentCount3 = 0;

    void IncrementCount3()
    {
        currentCount3++;
        StateHasChanged();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

### Final comments

As you can see the code is very simple for my troubleshooting, however the project is not, so re-creating would be a lot of work.

Any suggestions I might try? I'm really confused here.

Thanks in advance!

### Update with solution:

Turns out, as @dani hererra posted, I was missing "_Imports.razor" in the folder on my components from the attached Razor Class library like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` is listed on `_Imports.razor`:

```
@using System.Net.Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web  //<-----
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@using _your_namespace_
@using _your_namespace_.Shared
```

Comment: Yes it is on the client project! How do I ensure that the SharedLibrary is using the assemblies when referenced on the Client projet?

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed "_Imports.razor" missing in the folder on the attached "Razor Class Library". Strange that I never had the file in the beginning and it was working. Thank for the reply!